# why is makepkg not working in Arch linux?

Tags: linux, dwm

i'm trying to install this package https://github.com/w0ng/dwm
to configure/customize dwm window manager.

the thing is that I need to use "makepkg" to install it.
but when I do this **"# makepkg -efi"**, it outputs error  **"Running makepkg as root is not allowed as it can cause permanent, catastrophic damage to your system"**

so I made a new user, and changed the permission of all the files using "chmod 777" to give all permissions.

and when I do this **"$ makepkg -efi"** , it gives error **"You do not have write permission to create packages in /directory_name. Aborting..."**

what should I do to make "makepkg" work ?

Comment: So it must be something with the permissions.
Can you list the directory tree in which you want to build dwm?
And also the permissions of the directories? These informations would be very interesting. Here is a link to the [Arch Linux Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=84120 "arch linux forum") which describe a similar problem like yours.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not installing dwm from the package repositories with pacman?

Comment: did you really change the permissions of _all_ files on your system to 777, or was that merely unclear? Cause that sounds really dangerous...

Comment: btw using suckless software is not a good idea if you are new to arch and have no experience with building packages yourself

Answer (score 1):

makepkg should never be used as root. This would be dangerous because you are building user-made unofficial packages from AUR.

Download the package as a normal user like:

```
wget https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/package-query.tar.gz
```

Then extract the archive:

```
tar xvzf package-query
```

Then try to build it:

```
makepkg
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try creating the folder and downloading the archive as your non-root user.